# Getting blank page when coming from deeply nested child

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react-router for making a deeply nested routing, but getting a blank page when coming from deeply nested child to parent. How to solve this.

Here is a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vbt6tz?file=src%2Fcontainers%2FHome.jsx
Coming back from 2nd lv to 1st lv does not have any problem: eg. from /admin/setting i can come back to /admin using Admin-Dashborad
Coming back from 2nd lv to 0th lv gives blank page: eg. from /admin/setting i can not come back to / using Home, I mean it is not rendering Home

Same Situation appears in coming to Admin from Editor or Editor-Settings.

Thank you! If you've know this is already answered please link it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I actually figured it out, When I am using `BrowserRouter` in Parent it creates a container of those children, thus I can not route out of that and it creates the blank page. Instead of using another `BrowserRouter` at lv1 parent, i can just use `Switch`, and keep using the lv0 parent's `BrowserRouter` and it will be alright.

I also fixed the demo source, actually I solved it in the `Editor` Module where editor does not have its own `BrowserRouter` rather it is using `Admin`'s `BroserRouter` to route within admin. I still kept the problem of not being able to go back to `Home`, since that is a trivial solution.

Thanks.